# Excel: How to find the row dynamically with an Index Match formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are two tables:

1. Holds the actual values
2. Holds the ranking of the values by column in the first table

Please see the image below for an example:

[image]

As shown in the picture above, I want to find the row in the ranking table on the right that has a value of `3`, in the column `Tone_Rank`.

I'd then like to use that row to find the actually value corresponding to that row for the column starting with the same name on the table to the right. Here is what I have so far:

`=INDEX(B2:E6,MATCH(???),MATCH(M4,G1:J1,0))`

Comment: Why would the answer be `22` and not `23`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry you are correct, I will update

Comment: And are the ranks based on the rank order of the values?

Comment: Yes, the order of the values is how the rank table works, 1 being the lowest and 5 being the highest. But my real table has close to 500 rows, and 30 columns, just posting a smaller sample as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the Rank Table:

```
=SMALL(INDEX($B$2:$E$6,0,MATCH(LEFT(M4,FIND("_",M4)-1),$B$1:$E$1,0)),M2)
```

Comment: I have another question for you outside of the scope of the original question if you have a minute. Imagine if in cell M1, you have either the value "higher" or "lower". If the value is "higher", you'd rank the values in order that we have shown above. But if the value is "lower" you'd rank them in the opposite direction. How could you adjust your formulas above to account for this criteria?

Comment: If it is outside the scope please ask a new question.

Comment: I may be able to figure it out with just a small hint. If I just used and ```IF``` statement and then used ```Large``` instead of ```Small``` to flip the ranks would that work?

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:
`=INDEX($B$1:$E$6,MATCH($M$2,INDEX($G1:$J6,,MATCH($M$4,$G$1:$J$1,0)),0),MATCH($M$4,$G$1:$J$1,0))`

An extra index match is needed to get the correct column for searching the row number of your value.

You could even do this all at once without the _Rank helper table:
`=INDEX($A$1:$E$6,MATCH(LARGE(INDEX($A$1:$E$6,,MATCH($M$4,$A$1:$E$1,0)),$M$2),INDEX($A$1:$E$6,,MATCH($M$4,$A$1:$E$1,0)),0),MATCH($M$4,$A$1:$E$1,0))`
Note that the value in `M4` then needs to be "Tone" not "Tone_Rank"

I hope this helps (and yes, you can switch from large to small for flipping the ranking (high-low vs. Low-high).

Lol, I overlooked scott already posted a better version of this